Where can I find statutory orders made by the Privy Council of England?
I am researching early 20th century statutory orders made by the Privy Council, namely made under the Local Government Act 1899.
In the London Gazette, it is mentioned that on 15 May 1900 Orders in Council were passed.
I found the book Statutory Rules and Orders Other Than Those of a Local, Personal Or Temporary Character (varies Slightly).

I tried to find the order, but it was listed and not published as it was a local order.

I've tried researching but can't find anything online - is there a book or resource that contains local statutory orders?

Have you looked at the official UK legislation website? They're supposed to have all enacted legislation since 1267.

Yes I have. Sadly they don’t actually have all legislation, including local orders: https://www.legislation.gov.uk/changes/chron-tables/local/intro

Local secondary legislation is definitely pretty hard to track down, compared to legislation that is general or primary or both. Since 1948 it is easier because there is now a unified regime for all sorts of rule-making powers which were previously disparate, and which each had their own separate way of working. As you've discovered, there's no consolidated collection of local orders from the era, since they weren't systematically published at the time.
In this instance it appears we are looking at an Order in Council from 1900, made under the authority of the Local Government Act 1899. That Act gave "Her Majesty in Council" (in theory Queen Victoria carefully considering the advice of her ministers, in practice just the government) the power to set up London borough councils and establish boundaries. By section 15, the orders were to be prepared by a body of commissioners, and would have to be laid before Parliament in draft before being effective; either the Commons or the Lords could object, and if they didn't then the order could be made. This is now called the "draft negative procedure" but in 1899 they had to spell out all the details.
A consequence of that process is that the sessional papers of the Lords and the Commons will contain the draft text of each order. Parliamentary procedure doesn't allow these to be amended, only voted up or down. So the draft ought to be the same text as the resulting actual Order in Council. A bit of sleuthing might be needed if there had been a rejected draft, in order to find the actual correct version, but the dates in the screenshot above suggest that this order, like most, probably sailed through unbothered. If you happen to have institutional access to ProQuest then you can look up the 1900 sessional papers, e.g. on page 13 of Commons volume 74 for "Draft of an Order in Council for the Establishment of the Metropolitan Borough of Hammersmith and incorporating the Council thereof and for other purposes connected therewith".
In this particular instance, there also happens to be a published version of the drafts that's open-access, but we may not always be so lucky. In the general case, one has to hope that a text can be found in the records of the Privy Council itself (now in the National Archives), or else has been preserved by the person or locality to which the order refers.
For example, the Hammersmith order speaks in 3(3) of a copy of the boundary map being deposited with the Clerk of the London County Council. Although local government has changed several more times since 1899, the map is still apparently held in the London Archives under LCC/CL/LOC/02/018, and the actual made copy of the Order will be in the sibling LCC/CL/LOC/02/001. If we had not already seen the draft text then we could still find these records by guessing that the successor of the relevant local government body might have retained them. (Similarly, if looking for a non-statutory document like a patent of nobility, then we might guess that the current living members of the family would have kept their copy.) The maps would be useful in interpreting what is meant by the order saying things like "so much of the parish of Fulham as is coloured red and is numbered 9, 10, and 12 on the maps" (3(1)(b)).
There are likely also many contemporary maps showing the old parishes and the new boroughs, so one doesn't necessarily have to go back to the authoritative source. We might be fortunate enough to find that some helpful Victorian person had put out some more precise material at the time, for the benefit of Londoners who wanted to know where they now lived, and that some copy of that is now handily accessible. Some care would be needed to be sure of finding correct versions, given other boundary changes that might have happened over the years before and after. But this could be a reasonable proxy, depending on the detail of what you want to know, and whether it's convenient to travel to London to find out.

Hi there - thanks so much for such a detailed and well researched answer. I will be off to the archives to get those maps, which I can’t find anywhere!
